# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer giving error for primary field

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a project where I have created custom user by extending AbstractBaseUser and PermissionMixin, the model class is following.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True, validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)], max_length=10
    )
    password = models.CharField(
        null=False, blank=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)], max_length=225
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone_number"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    @staticmethod
    def hash_password(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        if not instance.is_staff and not instance.is_superuser:
            instance.set_password(instance.password)

    def get_token(self):
        return Token.objects.get(user=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number


# signals for Model User
pre_save.connect(User.hash_password, sender=User)
```

And the following ModelSerializer corresponding to it.

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["phone_number", "password"]
```

Now if If I pass the post data as:-

```
{
    "phone_number":8888888888,
    "password":12345678
}
```

### What I am getting:

- The serializer.is_valid() is returning False.
- if I am doing serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) then I am
  getting response as:

  {
  "phone_number": [
  "user with this phone number already exists."
  ]
  }

## My Doubts are:

- **I know that 8888888888 is already in the DataBase but I still want to
  access it using serializer.validated_data.get('phone_number', None)**
- **I also want to know the reason, why this is happening, it is acting
  like as if I am trying to insert a record, but if I pass phone number
  like 8888888887(Not present in the database), then its working fine**

Comment: Can you share your API View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `phone_number` is a primary key, it has unique validator by default.

You can add custom validators in the serializer as shown below.

```py
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["phone_number", "password"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'phone_number': {
                'validators': [MinLengthValidator(10)],
            }
        }
```

By adding the just the validators we require, the serializer only validates according to the given validators. if the `'validators': [],` are set to empty list, then no validation is performed on the particular field.

I have added `MinLengthValidator(10)` validator, which you have used in the **User** Model. You can import it and use it here.

Comment: Your approach worked, but I have suggested some changes, please look on it and change your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `phone_number` is the primary key. The primary key is a unique field, so you cannot have duplicate records. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key).

Comment: I know that, but I am not inserting anything in the DB, I am just getting this attribute in request object

Comment: but you are checking that the data is valid or not. So, it says that it is not. Checking for validation is the first step of inserting to DB. If you try to insert that data, it is not gonna permit it again.

Comment: oohh, any way to get rid of this?
should I define custom field in the serializer sub class?

Comment: you can get serializer.is_valid() to the inside of a try-except structure, so that you can handle the error without interrupting your request.